# Not getting the location

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I am making a app in which i have to show  a splash screen for 1/2 sec.While the splash is loading i have to get the user location.location accuracy is not concern.So for this i have written a code but always i get null from location.

Code

```
private Context context;

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    Location location;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public GetLocation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }


    private Location getLocation() {


        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(getProviderName());
        if (location == null) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProviderName(), 0, 0, this);
        }

        return location;


    }


    String getProviderName() {
         locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); // Chose your desired power consumption level.
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // Choose your accuracy requirement.
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(true); // Chose if speed for first location fix is required.
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false); // Choose if you use altitude.
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false); // Choose if you use bearing.
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false); // Choose if this provider can waste money :-)

        // Provide your criteria and flag enabledOnly that tells
        // LocationManager only to return active providers.
        return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Toast.makeText(context,""+location,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        Toast.makeText(context,provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Toast.makeText(context,provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        Toast.makeText(context,provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Usage

```
private void getLocation() {

        getLocation = new GetLocation(contextActivity);

        latitude = getLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = getLocation.getLongitude();

        if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {

            getLocation.stopUsingGPS();
        }
    }
```

Please do help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: post full code and also check object initialize or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation` returns null if a location hasn't been yet acquired. If it is case for your device, the following snippet

```
if (location == null) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProviderName(), 0, 0, this);
}
```

prevents you from registering the `LocationListener`, callback for your location manager.

Comment: How to do that sir,please can you explain

Comment: Sir please may you help me out?

Comment: remove the  `if`` , and use a broadcast an event when onLocationChanged is called

Comment: sir i have reomoved the if condition but still it not getting the toasts from the listner

Comment: you have to wait until the location is acquired. Trying using both the network and the gps provider. It will make things faster

Comment: Sir i had debugged the application and i was getting null in Network provider may be because the mobile doesnt have sim card but the wifi is on

Comment: wifi should be enough, just wait until the fix is acquired

Comment: can we chat sir please???

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not updating location in onLocationChanged. Are you getting location non null object in your toast text?

My answer would be updating location member variable with the location received with onLocationChange event.

Comment: No i also not getting the toast

Comment: Hmm... Try with fused location API to get location. Fused location API are fast compared to location manager and provides more accurate locations as well. 
Find more info here : https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html